# Issue between thread and context - Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-context

I'm trying to implement a thread so that I can send GPS coordinates in the background. I think I have a good start but I'm having a little trouble. Where it says `locManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);`.

I'm getting an error on context (before getSystemService) which says "context cannot be resolved." I call this class from my main activity with the following statement `new FindLocation(getBaseContext()).start(usr_id1);` maybe that has something to do with the problem.

```
public class FindLocation extends Thread {

private LocationManager locManager;
private LocationListener locListener;

Context ctx;
public String userId;

public FindLocation(Context ctx) {
     this.ctx = ctx;
}

 public void start(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        super.start();
      }

 @Override
public void run() {
    final String usr = userId;
    
    //get a reference to the LocationManager
    locManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
   
    //checked to receive updates from the position
    locListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            
            String lat = String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()); 
            String lon = String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude());
            
            JSONArray jArray;
            String result = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            StringBuilder sb = null;
            
             ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", usr));
             
            //http post
            try{
                
                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/test/example.php");     
                 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                 is = entity.getContent();
                 }catch(Exception e){
                     Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
                }
            
            //convert response to string
            try{
                  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                   sb = new StringBuilder();
                   sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            
                   String line="0";
                   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                  sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    result=sb.toString();
                    }
            
                    catch(Exception e){
                          Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                            

                    }
    
            try{
                  jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                  JSONObject json_data=null;
                  for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                         json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                         String ct_name = json_data.getString("phoneID");
                         //stop = true;
                         Log.i("User ID", ct_name);
                         if(ct_name == usr) {
                             locManager.removeUpdates(locListener);
                         }
                         else{
                             Log.i("User ID", "NONE");
                         }
                     } 
                  }
    
                  catch(Exception e){
                        //Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                        
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/test/example.php");

                        try {
                               List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                               nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat)); 
                               nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", lon));
                               nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", usr));
                               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs1));
                               httpclient.execute(httppost);
                               Log.i("SendLocation", "Yes"); 
                         } 
                         catch (ClientProtocolException g) {
                             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                         } catch (IOException f) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 
            } 
        }       
        
        
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ 
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
        }
    };
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 6000, 0, locListener);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public FindLocation(Context ctx) {
     this.ctx = ctx;
    }
```

according to what you had posted you should use `ctx` instead of `context`

Comment: Ok, I changed it, but now I get the error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` and it has something to do with the line `locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 6000, 0, locListener);` right at the end. Any idea why?

Comment: it is another issue but standing at documentation your thread should have a looper inside. You could read the doc about Looper here:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
locManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

by

```
locManager = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```